# How to implement admin login and logout using Django REST framework?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, postman

I have been given a task to authenticate admin login programmatically and logout as well.

I am able to to do login but on logged out when I check which user I am logging out it says AnonymousUser. How can I make sure I log out current user which is logged it.

I am using Django REST framework and testing it on Postman.

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def adminLogin(request):
    
    if(request.method=="POST"):
        username = request.data["username"]
        password = request.data["password"]

        authenticated_user = authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
        if authenticated_user != None:

            if(authenticated_user.is_authenticated and authenticated_user.is_superuser):
                login(request,authenticated_user)
                return JsonResponse({"Message":"User is Authenticated. "})   
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"message":"User is not authenticated. "})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"Message":"Either User is not registered or password does not match"})

@api_view(["POST"])
def adminLogout(request):
    print(request.user)
    logout(request)
    return JsonResponse({"message":"LoggedOut"})
```

Comment: are you passing the token on logout API? what print(request.user) is printing?

Comment: login/logout for an API makes not much sense, since it usually does not use cookies, but works with means like a JWT token.

Comment: yes IN HEADERS I AM PASSING X-CSRFToken and now when i click submit it says csrf token missing or incorrect but it is in adminlogout and 

even in admin login when i press again it says csrf token missing

Comment: zilay it is printing AnonymousUser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging in/logging out with a REST API makes not much sense. The idea of logging in/logging out, at least how Django implements it, is by means of the session, so with a *cookie* that has the session id.

API clients like Postman usually do *not* work with cookies: each request is made more or less independent of the previous one. If you thus make the next request without a reference to the session, then the view will not link a user to that request. Clients like AJAX that runs on the browser of course can work with cookies, since these are embedded in the browser that manages cookies. You can work with cookies in postman as specified in [this tutorial <sup>[learning postman]</sup>](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/cookies/), but this is usually not how an API is supposed to work.

This is why APIs usually work with a token, for example a JWT token. When authenticating, these are given a token that might be valid for a short amount of time, and subsequently it uses that token to make any other request that should be authorized.

As the [Django REST framework documentation on *`TokenAuthentication`* <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) says, you can define views that create, and revoke tokens. The page also discusses *session authentication* that thus can be used for AJAX requests.

But likely you are thus using the wrong means to do proper authentication for your REST API, and you thus might want to work with a token like a JWT token instead.

Comment: I used your answer and created token for admin login, but how do i create a logout using jwt?

Comment: @James: you can blacklist a token: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52431850/67579 but usually the token will expire quite soon and thus no longer work.